# How to append to a multi-page TIFF?

Tags: tiff-format

Can you append another image to a multi-page TIFF without having to load all the existing images?

Comment: Perhaps I should have said that I want to do it in Mathematica, but I thought that was implicit.

Comment: @Simon, you can't change the structure of arbitrary Tiff without reading the header with description of the frame size, current number of frames, etc... You can do it using low-level routines in MMA but this is not the best tool for such exercises.